# Is there any difference in mesh generated by Bool Tool addon vs default Boolean modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Let's imaging that I have two meshes and I want union/diff/intersect them. Probably the default way to do that is to apply a Boolean modifier. The other way is to use the Bool Tool addon. Will these two approaches always generate the same output mesh (if I apply modifiers)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it makes any difference, *BoolTool* is just an addon that makes booleans easier to use, for example it makes the boolean object transparent without the need to go into its display options. Apart from that it creates a classic *Boolean* modifier.